# Parsing Json response with Java

Tags: java, json, rest

I have this restful web service http://firstsw.besaba.com/get_all.php?tab=doctors&cond=doc_id=2, I tested it with [Advanced Rest Client plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and it work well. I want to parse the Json response with java code, so my code is:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.*;

public class JsonArray {

    public JsonArray() {
        initJson();
    }
    public void initJson() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://firstsw.besaba.com/get_all.php?tab=doctors&cond=doc_id=2");     
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(url);
            String success = obj.getString("success");
            System.out.println(success+"/n");
            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("element");
            for(int i=0;i<att.length;i++){
                String doc_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("doc_id");
                String doc_firstname = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("doc_firstname");
                String doc_lastname = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("doc_lastname");
                System.out.println("doc_id: "+doc_id+"/n"+"doc_firstname:"+doc_firstname+"/n"+"doc_lastname: "+doc_lastname);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JsonArray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get those exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["success"] not found.
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["element"] not found.
```

Comment: Please provide the JSON response from your service.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza use the provided URL: http://pastebin.com/bRsMA5H2 :)

Comment: You couldn't create JSONObject from URL. You should obtain response from service as a first step.

Comment: Use javadoc: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html . I don't really like those creating constructors with `Object` as it makes novices think they can pass something like `URL` there.

Comment: {
success: 1
element: [1]
  0:  {
  doc_id: "2"
  doc_blocked: "2"
  doc_firstname: "bla bla"
  doc_lastname: "bla bla"
  doc_degree: "Professor"
  doc_desc: "aaaaaa"
  doc_image: "bbbbbbbbb"
  doc_address: "ccccccc"
  doc_city: "dddddd"
  doc_zip: "eeeee"
  doc_country: "fffff"
  doc_latitude: "ggggg"
  doc_longitude: "hhhhh"
  doc_telephone: "iiiii"
  doc_mobile: "123456789"
  doc_email: "aaaa@bbbb.com"
  doc_url: "www.aaaaa.com"
  doc_passsword: "vvvvvv"
  doc_workhours: "xxxxx"
  doc_dated: "2014-11-26 00:00:00"
  gal_id: "2"
  pol_id: "3"
  treat_id: "4"
      }
}

Comment: @user3417644 this should be 1) edit for question 2) formatted as I did here: http://pastebin.com/bRsMA5H2

Comment: @mkrakhin how can I obtain response from service?

Comment: @user3417644 Personally I prefer some JAX-RS clients (like Jersey client), but take a look thorugh LuiggiMendoza answer. I think his suggestions are more easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a library like [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) or [UniRest](http://unirest.io/java.html) that executes the http request (GET, POST, etc.) against the external server and returns the proper response. Here's an example using UniRest:

```
String url = "http://firstsw.besaba.com/get_all.php";
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get(url)
    .queryString("tab", "doctor")
    .queryString("cond", "doc_id=2")
    .asJson();
String jsonContent = jsonResponse.getBody().toString();
//prints the JSON response
System.out.println(jsonContent);
//and you could create your JSON object from here
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
```

Comment: I use your code and I add UniRest.jar in my class path but I get this exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet
 at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)`

Comment: @user3417644 unirest depends on other libraries. Check here: *Don't forget to also install the dependencies (org.json, httpclient 4.3.5, httpmime 4.3.5, httpasyncclient 4.0.2) in the classpath too* under *Installing/Without Maven* section.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is

```
            url = new URL("http://firstsw.besaba.com/get_all.php?tab=doctors&cond=doc_id=2");     
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(url);
```

You must not use the url as parameter for the JSONObject(String) constructor.

You have to request the server first and get the json string of the http response

For a get request you should use code like this

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tab", "doctors"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cond", "doc_id=2"));

HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
httpParams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

final String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");
final String urlRequest = "http://firstsw.besaba.com/get_all.php?" + paramString;
final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlRequest);
final HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

for post request

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tab", "doctors"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cond", "doc_id=2"));

final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
httpParams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://firstsw.besaba.com/get_all.php");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
final HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: You forgot to specify that you're using Apache HttpComponents.

Comment: @Martin_Ma are you using any extra library?

Comment: I copied the code from an old android project of mine. I think the library is part of androids default librarys.    You are right, it´s out of apache httpcomponents. You have to add the library to your project

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code the line JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(url) is problematic.
According to the javadoc the url is seen as an Object.
This will not give the desired result.
Better is to get the json content as String first.
Replace this part :

```
        url = new URL("http://firstsw.besaba.com/get_all.php?tab=doctors&cond=doc_id=2");

        String content = (String)url.getContent();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content);
        String success = obj.getString("success");
        System.out.println(success+"/n");
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("element");
```

See the javadoc where I found this info:
[json.org](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String`